# 2 elements in a grid cell

Tags: wpf, vb.net, grid

I replace dynamically a label by a dropdownlist and a checkbox  in a cell in a grid like this

```
Private Sub replaceUiElementInGrid(ByVal newUiElement As UIElement, ByVal uiElementToReplace As UIElement, ByVal gridToAddNewUiElement As Grid)
        If gridToAddNewUiElement.Children.Contains(uiElementToReplace) Then
            Grid.SetRow(newUiElement, Grid.GetRow(uiElementToReplace))
            Grid.SetColumn(newUiElement, Grid.GetColumn(uiElementToReplace))
            Dim pos As Integer = gridToAddNewUiElement.Children.IndexOf(uiElementToReplace)
            gridToAddNewUiElement.Children.RemoveAt(pos)
            gridToAddNewUiElement.Children.Add(newUiElement)

            Try
                Dim label As Label = DirectCast(uiElementToReplace, Label)
                If (label.Name.Contains("ACTIVITY")) Then
                    Dim checkbox As CheckBox
                    checkbox = New CheckBox()
                    checkbox.Content = "Direction"

                    checkbox.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right
                    'Dim uiCheckbox As UIElement = DirectCast(checkbox, UIElement)
                    Grid.SetRow(checkbox, Grid.GetRow(uiElementToReplace))
                    Grid.SetColumn(checkbox, Grid.GetColumn(uiElementToReplace))
                    gridToAddNewUiElement.Children.Add(checkbox)
                    AddHandler checkbox.Click, AddressOf filtrerDropDownActiviteEvent
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

The problem is that the checkbox is over the dropdown. I tried `checkbox.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right`
but the dropdown takes always all the cell width.

All i want is a dropdown at left and a checkbox at right but I can't figure how to do it

Thank you

Here is the final version

```
 Private Sub replaceUiElementInGrid(ByVal newUiElement As UIElement, ByVal uiElementToReplace As UIElement, ByVal gridToAddNewUiElement As Grid)
    If gridToAddNewUiElement.Children.Contains(uiElementToReplace) Then
        Dim panel As WrapPanel = New WrapPanel
        Grid.SetRow(panel, Grid.GetRow(uiElementToReplace))
        Grid.SetColumn(panel, Grid.GetColumn(uiElementToReplace))
        Dim pos As Integer = gridToAddNewUiElement.Children.IndexOf(uiElementToReplace)
        gridToAddNewUiElement.Children.RemoveAt(pos)
        panel.Children.Add(newUiElement)

        Try
            Dim label As Label = DirectCast(uiElementToReplace, Label)
            If (label.Name.Contains("ACTIVITY")) Then
                Dim checkbox As CheckBox
                checkbox = New CheckBox()
                checkbox.Content = "Direction"

                'checkbox.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right
                'Dim uiCheckbox As UIElement = DirectCast(checkbox, UIElement)
                panel.Children.Add(checkbox)
                AddHandler checkbox.Click, AddressOf filtrerDropDownActiviteEvent
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        gridToAddNewUiElement.Children.Add(panel)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap a grid or another panel type around the dropdown and checkbox. Format it, and then replace the label with the grid (or whatever).

Edit:

Just to be more specific, now you end up with this:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox />
    <CheckBox />
</Grid>
```

But should go for something like this:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".50" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".50" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="0"  />
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="1"  />
        </Grid>
 </Grid>
```